# Вставка в определенную таблицу по условию

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, oracle

Хочу сделать такую вставку:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (DATE1)
SELECT DATE1
FROM Table2 
WHERE PERIOD_TYPE = 0 AND NEWNUM < 10000;
```

Можно ли задать имя целевой таблицы `Table1` исходя из условия:

```
PERIOD_TYPE = 0 AND NEWNUM < 10000
```

в `WHERE` предикате исходной таблицы `Table2`?

То есть:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (DATE1)
    SELECT DATE1
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE PERIOD_TYPE = 1 AND NEWNUM < 10000;
INSERT INTO Table4 (DATE1)
    SELECT DATE1
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE PERIOD_TYPE = 1 AND NEWNUM > 9999;
```

Но надо сделать одной конструкцией, а не 10-ю отдельными вставками.

Comment: Смотря куда вставлять.  Приведите пожалуйста пример данных и желаемый результат.

Comment: @0xdb В инсерте же написано вроде. Выбирать из одной таблицы и вставлять в разные таблицы исходя из того, какие именно данные были выбраны. Для простоты во всех таблицах просто даты. PeriodType 1/0. Newnum 0...99999999.

Comment: Да, но у вас две метки в вопросе, sql-server и oracle, значит два решения.

Comment: @0xdb Понял. В идеале -универсально. Если так нельзя, то придется два решения. Важнее SQLServer

Comment: Динамический SQL. Строите строку запроса в зависимости от значения, и выполняете её. Хотя разумнее процедурку замутить - передаёшь ей значение, а она сама разберётся. И вот там как раз я бы не поленился десять запросов написать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В *Oracle* БД решение однозначно с [INSERT ALL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) (см. *multi_table_insert*).

**Воспроизводимый рабочий пример**

Подготовим данные вкл. целевые таблицы с различной структурой:

```
create table items as
    select rownum id, 'name '||rownum name, date'2020-01-20'+(0.1*rownum) created
    from xmlTable ('1 to 6');

create table target1 as select id, name from items where 0=1;
create table target2 as select name, created from items where 0=1;
create table target3 as select * from items where 0=1;
```

Сама вставка:

```
insert all 
when id <= 2 then into target1 values (id, name)
when id >= 5 then into target2 values (name, created)
else into target3
select * from items;

6 rows inserted.
```

Результат:

```
select 'target1' target, id, name, date'1900-01-01' created 
from target1 t union all 
select 'target2' target, 0, name, created 
from target2 t union all 
select 'target3' target, t.* 
from target3 t;

TARGET          ID NAME       CREATED            
------- ---------- ---------- -------------------
target1          1 name 1     1900-01-01 00:00:00
target1          2 name 2     1900-01-01 00:00:00
target2          0 name 5     2020-01-20 12:00:00
target2          0 name 6     2020-01-20 14:24:00
target3          3 name 3     2020-01-20 07:12:00
target3          4 name 4     2020-01-20 09:36:00
```